# How can I add another row of on top of this div?

Tags: html, css

Hello I need some help trying add another row on top of these four in the picture
[image]
like a table but not using a table.
I'm pretty new to html so I don't know how to put them on top, since when I add a new div, it goes besides it rather than on top of it.

Edit: Someone said I should put a picture of what I want to happen so here it is [sizes are off but you get the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1A2e5.png)

```css
body {
  background-color: #61162d;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.button-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.button-box {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  width: calc(25% - 20px);
  transition: transform 0.3s;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 15px 15px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 681px) {
  .button-container {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80%;
    height: 90%;
  }
  .button-box {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80%;
  }
  .btn {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80%;
  }
}

.button-box:hover {
  transform: translateY(-5px);
}

.button-box h2 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.button-box .btn {
  background-color: #b5a36a;
  border: 2px solid #b5a36a;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  /* Adjust this value for vertical spacing between buttons */
  transition: background-color 0.3s, color 0.3s;
}

.button-box .btn:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #b5a36a;
}

.logos-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="button-container">
  <div class="button-box">
    <h2>Title 1</h2>
    <a href="#" class="btn">Button 1A</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn">Button 1B</a>
  </div>
  <div class="button-box">
    <h2>Title 2</h2>
    <a href="#" class="btn">Button 2A</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn">Button 2B</a>
  </div>
  <div class="button-box">
    <h2>Title 3</h2>
    <a href="#" class="btn">Button 3A</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn">Button 3B</a>
  </div>
  <div class="button-box">
    <h2>Title 4</h2>
    <a href="#" class="btn">Button 4A</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn">Button 4B</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm not familiar with divs, so I using display flex, z index, moving the divs into another div but nothing seemed to have worked. It still just put them side by side.

Comment: Why don't you show an image of what is the desired output? You're showing us some code that is not related or pointing in the desired direction.

Comment: Your requirements are too vague. But if you just want to put a logo *inside* each box at the top, just try starting by putting the logo image above the `h2`. Then you can work on positioning it as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `display:flex;` in the `body` it will always try to put it side by side.
You shouldn't use `display:flex;` in the `body`

Comment: I'm planning on putting a logo on top of each of the boxes. So no not a button

Comment: Dont use `display:flex;` in body.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you need to keep those buttons in the center of the viewport always so maintaining that I created a wrapper in the html and added the following CSS changes:

```
body{
    background-color: #61162d;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/* It's position needs to be absolute to allow those buttons to remain in the center */
.new-row{
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    /* you may need to adjust this top value according to the content you put inside of it */
    top: calc(50vh - 193px);
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

/* changing the container position to static for the smaller screen */
@media screen and (max-width: 681px){
    .new-row{
        position: static;
    }
}

.wrapper {
    background-color: #61162d;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

```css
body{
    background-color: #61162d;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/* It's position needs to be absolute to allow those buttons to remain in the center */
.new-row{
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    /* you may need to adjust this top value according to the content you put inside of it */
    top: calc(50vh - 193px);
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

/* changing the container position to static for the smaller screen */
@media screen and (max-width: 681px){
    .new-row{
        position: static;
    }
}

.wrapper {
    background-color: #61162d;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
}

.button-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.button-box {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    width: calc(25% - 20px);
    transition: transform 0.3s;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 15px 15px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 681px) {
    .button-container {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 80%;
        height: 90%;
    }
    .button-box {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 80%;
    }
    .btn {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 80%;
    }
}

.button-box:hover {
    transform: translateY(-5px);
}

.button-box h2 {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.button-box .btn {
    background-color: #b5a36a;
    border: 2px solid #b5a36a;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 6px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    margin: 5px 0;
    /* Adjust this value for vertical spacing between buttons */
    transition: background-color 0.3s, color 0.3s;
}

.button-box .btn:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #b5a36a;
}

.logos-container {
    display: flex;
    width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <!-- outside the wrapper container -->
    <div class="new-row">I am a new row and above the button-container row</div>
    
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="button-container">            
            <div class="button-box">
            <h2>Title 1</h2>
            <a href="#" class="btn">Button 1A</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn">Button 1B</a>
            </div>
            <div class="button-box">
            <h2>Title 2</h2>
            <a href="#" class="btn">Button 2A</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn">Button 2B</a>
            </div>
            <div class="button-box">
            <h2>Title 3</h2>
            <a href="#" class="btn">Button 3A</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn">Button 3B</a>
            </div>
            <div class="button-box">
            <h2>Title 4</h2>
            <a href="#" class="btn">Button 4A</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn">Button 4B</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```css
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  body {
    background-color: #61162d;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
  }

  .button-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  }

  .logo-box {
    padding: 20px;
    flex-direction: column;
    display: flex;
  }

  .button-box {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    transition: transform 0.3s;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 15px 0 0 0;
  }

  @media only screen and (max-width: 681px) {
    .button-container {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 80%;
      height: 90%;
    }
    .button-box {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 80%;
    }
    .btn {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 80%;
    }
  }

  .button-box:hover {
    transform: translateY(-5px);
  }

  .button-box h2 {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }

  .button-box .btn {
    background-color: #b5a36a;
    border: 2px solid #b5a36a;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 6px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    margin: 5px 0;
    /* Adjust this value for vertical spacing between buttons */
    transition: background-color 0.3s, color 0.3s;
  }

  .button-box .btn:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #b5a36a;
  }

  .logos-container {
    display: flex;
    width: 80%;
  }
```

```html
<div class="button-container">
    <div class="logo-box">
        Your logo
        <div class="button-box">
            <h2>Title 1</h2>
            <a href="#" class="btn">Button 1A</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn">Button 1B</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="logo-box">
        Your logo
        <div class="button-box">
            <h2>Title 2</h2>
            <a href="#" class="btn">Button 2A</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn">Button 2B</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="logo-box">
        Your logo
        <div class="button-box">
            <h2>Title 3</h2>
            <a href="#" class="btn">Button 3A</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn">Button 3B</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="logo-box">
        Your logo
        <div class="button-box">
            <h2>Title 4</h2>
            <a href="#" class="btn">Button 4A</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn">Button 4B</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```